Type error while transforming input via Zod
I'm trying to write a decoder function (decode) that takes in a Zod schema and an unknown input. It should be able to both validate the input and transform it if the Zod codec's input and output types are different.
When I try to do it like this:
import { ZodSchema, z } from 'zod'

const DateFromString = z.string().transform(input => new Date(input))

const Event = z.object({ timestamp: DateFromString })

const decode = <T>(schema: ZodSchema<T>, data: unknown): T => schema.parse(data)

const { timestamp } = decode(Event, { timestamp: '2024-01-01' })

I get the following type error:

The types of '_input.timestamp' are incompatible between these types.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Date'.(2345)

Is there a way to fix this type error and make sure that the timestamp variable at the last line is of type Date?
Another way to ask my question is how can I define just one decode function rather than repeating the implementation just for the sake of typing:
import { ZodArray, ZodObject, ZodRawShape, ZodUnion, ZodUnionOptions } from 'zod'

const decodeObject = <T extends ZodRawShape>(schema: ZodObject<T>, data: unknown) =>
  schema.parse(data)

const decodeArray = <T extends ZodRawShape>(schema: ZodArray<ZodObject<T>>, data: unknown) =>
  schema.parse(data)

const decodeUnion = <T extends ZodUnionOptions>(schema: ZodUnion<T>, data: unknown) =>
  schema.parse(data)


The decode function is wrongly inferring the type as shown in the docs. This version will correctly infer ZodSchema, ZodPipeline and ZodEffects
function decode<T extends z.ZodTypeAny>(schema: T, data: unknown) {
    return schema.parse(data) as z.infer<T>;
}

You probably want to validate the Date type, for this use a zod.custom:
// With 'custom' we need to provide our own validation
const DateType = z.custom<Date>(
    (input) => new Date(input).toString() !== 'Invalid Date'
); // Weak validation

const DateFromString = z
    .string() // validate string
    .transform((v) => new Date(v)) // transform to Date
    .pipe(DateType); // validate Date


Careful, just calling new Date() is not a proper way to validate dates. e.g: new Date(0) is 'valid'; new Date(12345) is also 'valid'.

Also, Zod has a validation for string in timestamp format:
const DateFromString = z.string().date();


Many thanks, your version of the decode function did the trick for me even without having to change my original version of DateFromString.

You just made me realize that the problem is the decode fn. I will fix the answer.
